# entity framework code first using existing database

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, code-first

I have started learning Entity framework and have a problem. I have created a code first mvc project and I don't want to drop the database when the model changes. What can I do other than **DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges** in my initializer class so that the database and the tables stays along with the data?

Comment: study more :) you can switch to DB First Approach (EDMX file) or use `migrations` in code first

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to use an initializer at all. This is valid:

```
Database.SetInitializer<YourContext>(null);
```

<strike>And in your configuration file set `AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;`</strike>

Then you can do the migrations yourself.

Comment: actually, the migrations do not need to be disabled. Because the Context has no initializer and therefore will not verify the model, it would never attempt to Create a migration to the current model.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro, Thanks for the info, I wasn't actually aware of that.